# Loop through a clinicaltrials.gov api query

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is just one column of "NCT numbers" (identifiers for clinical trials) Example rows like this->

```
NCT<-structure(list(`NCT Number` = c("NCT01772004", "NCT02513394", 
"NCT02873195", "NCT01872975", "NCT02750826", "NCT02517398")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using this code, I can query the clinicaltrials.gov api and return some info about each of those studies:

```
library(clinicaltrialr)
library(pbapply)

trials_list <- pbapply::pblapply(NCT$`NCT Number`, ct_read_trial, cl = 7)
trials <- dplyr::bind_rows(trials_list)
```

Code will work great, returns something that looks like this:

[image]

Problem is, that only works when I send it a small chunk of data, not all 600 rows that I want to send.

If I try to send my entire dataframe, I get this error:

[image]

I BELIEVE that error is caused by a limit on rows at clinicaltrials.gov, pictured here:

[image]

Is there a way I can automatically split my 600 row dataframe into smaller chunks and send those? Looping through each chunk?  I could manually split it, but I'll have to do this task monthly or so.

Comment: Do you know which query specifically causes the error? Is it the same one every time? Also, this package doesn't really seem to call the API, it rather loads the actual page as XML (e.g. it just fetches https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCTxxxx?resultsxml=true). You can try that request manually.

Comment: try https://clinicaltrials.gov/data-api/api and see `filter.ids` param. Looks like you can batch 1000 studies at a time so slice your full delimited list accordingly and pass to a custom request function. Handle results as desired.